# Version and Retention Policy

Tags: versioning

I am new to Share Point and looking for a solution to the following problem.
I have enabled and set up versioning and limited it to 4 versions and a document retention policy to 3 years. As versioning takes precedence over retention policy the earliest version gets deleted as soon as the 5 version is created. I am looking to somehow save the earliest version before the 5th one is created.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem?

Thanks,

SM

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions:

Either a custom workflow to take into account your parameters (this will be a better solution for you since you don't know C#)

[Introduction to workflows](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-workflows-HA010154424.aspx)

[Example workflow videos](http://www.sheltonblog.com/archive/2007/11/04/series-of-sharepoint-workflow-how-to-videos.aspx) (Some good videos here)

[Versioning in SharePoint 2010](http://blog.fpweb.net/sharepoint-2010-versioning/)

You workflow needs to check the version and work accordingly to your rules, the links above will guide you on the basics of Workflows in SharePoint Designer.

Please either update your question or open a new question about any part you may get stuck at. It is a very large subject to cover all of, so specific questions can be answered more easily.

**The alternative would of been**

Clever usage of event receivers to determine actions - This is a C#/Visual Studio solution which as a developer I would prefer for myself. Workflows are most definitely more up your ally than this as they are graphical and logical.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I'll give solutions both a try. Unfortunately I don't know C#.net.

Comment: Then go down the workflow route. I will hunt you out a good beginner guide and custom versioning workflow guide for you.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Thanks. You are of great help.